# Changing the command prompt of Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

I have found myself to grow fond to CentOS's command prompt which looks like the following:

```
 [user@host directory]$ cmd
```

I, personally, do not like how Mac OS X Terminal is laid out, which is:

```
 host:directory user$ cmd
```

Is there any way to change the prompt of Terminal's commands to make it look more like the first one? I am very new to these things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using bash, simply do
PS1='[\u@\h \w]$ '

More details and options in man bash (search for PROMPTING)

If tcsh, do man tcsh and search for "prompt"

Comment: Also, I had to use \W instead of \w, because CentOS shows just the directory name, not the path.